# What services would i need to implement a real time matchmaking system for chat application

Tags: amazon-web-services

**Requirements**:

- Real time matchmaking system that matches two users based on their input keyword interest. e.g. User 1 has interests of ['AWS', 'Azure', 'GCP'] while User 2 has interests of ['AWS', 'Azure'], since there is at least 1 common interest this should be sufficient to match the two persons. Basically Omegle.

**My Incomplete Solution**:

- Store users looking for a new match in a DynamoDB table. Remove them from the table when they stopped looking for a new match.

**Problem**:

- Within 5 seconds, I need to look for a match for a user constantly. Given that the list of users looking for a match is stored in a DynamoDB table, is there a way I could search & filter the table in real-time constantly until 5 seconds is done?

**Other Ideas**:

- AWS has GameLift which does the matchmaking but I'm not sure if this would be the best pick given that this is not a game application but rather a chat application.